# Webpack share file across bundles separately

Tags: jquery, typescript, webpack, webpack-5

Using webpack 5.26

I have common file js that common function used across bundles

CommonFunctions

- Fun1
- Fun2

Budle1

- CommonFunction - Fun1

Bundle2

- CommonFunction - Fun2

If any changes to CommonFunction-Fun1. Bundle1 and Budle2  is updated by webpack

The requirement is only appropriate bundle should be updated.
Here webpack configuration file

```
  module.exports = {
    entry: {
        bundle1: './bundle1.ts',
        bundle2: './bundle2.ts'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts'] // add your other extensions here
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../JsFiles"),
        library: "testCommon",

    },
    module: {
        rules: [{ test: /\.ts$/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader' }],
    },

    mode: 'development'
}


--CommonFunctions.ts
export class CommonFunctions {
    Fun1() { };
    Fun2() { };
}

--bundle1.ts

import CommonFunctions from '../Js'
export class bundle1 {
    b1() { CommonFunctions.Fun1 }
}

--bundle2.ts
import CommonFunctions from '../Js'
export class bundle2 {
    b2() { CommonFunctions.Fun2 }
}
```

How to make common / seprate file/ module that shares acorss budles using webpack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            Util: {
                test: path.resolve(__dirname, 'CommonFunctions'),
                name: 'CommonFunctions',
                enforce: true,
                chunks: "all"
            },
            
        },
    },
},
```

By creating a separate chunk webpack is created separated JS file now I can load common file separately.